# Why i should wrap ListItemButton with ListItem in Material-UI 5? What is the purpose of ListItem?

Tags: material-ui, listitem

Can someone explain me whats the purpose of the ListItem component? In the examples of Material-UI I see it sometimes wrapping ListItemButton and sometimes not?

here w/o:

[image]

here w/:

[image]

there is no difference. here side by side comparison:
[image]

also the API is looking similar if im not wrong?!?

so whats the point?